# Looking up GUIDs from JPA

Tags: java, sql-server, jpa

What should have been a nobrainer has turned out to be a bit more complicated than i imagined, so i hope someone can help.

Basically I'm having a classical order database table in SQL Server like:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[order] (
    [orderid] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [uniqueid] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [revision] [int] NOT NULL,
    <lots of other stuff...>
  CONSTRAINT [PK_order] PRIMARY KEY ([orderid]),
  CONSTRAINT [UK_order] UNIQUE ([uniqueid], [revision])
)
```

Looking up an order from SQL Management Studio by (uniqueid, revision) works like a dream so

```
SELECT *
  FROM [order]
 WHERE [uniqueid] = '9E2822E9-4D08-4A25-8A86-ADAF8DB511CE' AND [revision] = 5;
```

returns whatever is appropriate.

The problem arises when i try to access the orders table from my JPA framework. This is my entity mapping for the orders table:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="[order]")
public class Order implements Serializable {
  @Id
    private long orderid;

  private String uniqueid;

  private int revision;

  <lots of other stuff...>
}
```

Looking up an order by orderid works like a dream, say

```
public Order loadOrder(long orderid) {
    return JPA.getManager().find(Order.class, orderid);
}
```

returns whatever is appropriate.

The problem arises when i try to retrieve an order by (uniqueid, revision) from my JPA framework. This fails miserably:

```
public Order loadOrder(String uniqueid, int version) {
    Query q = JPA.getManager().createQuery("SELECT o FROM Order o WHERE o.uniqueid=:uniqueid AND o.version=:version");
    q.setParameter("uniqueid", uniqueid).setParameter("version", version);
    ...
}
```

with a java.sql.SQLException: Conversion failed when converting from a character string to uniqueidentifier. 
Googling for the SQLException message yields a ton of results, but all have to do with *generating* unique identifiers. I'm not generating anything - just trying to look up existing values.

I have a nagging feeling that i'm missing something obvious, but I must admit that I'm stuck. Any help?

BTW JPA.getManager() returns an instance of javax.persistence.EntityManager.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the uniqueidentifier type in SQL Server, and it seem JPA is also not.

You could try using a varchar type instead.

Does you JDBC driver support uniqueidentifier, if it does how does it want the type bound?  You may need to do some conversion.

If you are using EclipseLink, you could use a Converter.

http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.4/jpa/extensions/a_converter.htm#CHDEHJEB